# ExtJs store getModifiedRecords()

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a grid in a view that gets populated by a store. I update store records by calculating some numbers. Therefore, the method getModifiedRecords() returns the one that have been modified. My question comes at this point.

Is it possible to tell when to start getting modified records? For example, I want to make calculations and then update the store. My app requires that at this point getModifiedRecords() should return nothing.

If I make changes to the store later, then it should return modified records.

Answer (score 1):

`getModifiedRecords` will return all records that are:

- new: `item.phantom === true && item.isValid()`
- updated: `item.dirty === true && item.phantom !== true && item.isValid()`

so as soon as if you create a record or set a record field these will be returned by this function.

Comment: This is correct but does not fix the problem. Maybe there is another function or another way. Record is updated, thus, it gets returned by `getModifiedRecords`. The problem is that after I update the record, I want `getModifiedRecords` to return nothing. So, I do not know if I can define a starting point for `getModifiedRecords` or if I should try another way. Add new records or update existing but decide from what point to start counting to find them.

Comment: so you use `record.set()` and then want to return nothing from `getModifiedRecords()` ? so you need to use `record.commit()` after your update which will set `dirty = false` and everything should be fine.